# Exporting Map with Table - formatting disappears?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, export

I'm working in ArcMap 10.3. I have a table that I've copied directly from Excel into ArcMap. In the layout view, all the formatting (highlighting and cell borders) have been properly imported. However, when exporting, the formatting for the table disappears. I've tried exporting it as both PDF and JPEB, but it disappears on both. Is there some way that I can export with the formatting intact?

[image]

Comment: I haven't done this in a while but I used to have this problem often and I worked around it by taking a screenshot of the Excel table and inserting that into the layout, instead of copying/pasting from Excel.

Comment: @DanC that's a good workaround. It works for the export as well. Thanks for your help!